# Как распечатать страницу с экранными стилями?

Tags: google-chrome, media-queries, печать

Есть страница, у которой стили для печати прописаны просто ужасно.

Как распечатать или сохранить в pdf её со стилями из `media=screen`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Некоторое время назад хром научился делать скриншот страницы или выбранного dom-элемента.

Если устраивает сохранение картинки в png (например, для последующей печати на принтере), то можно нажать <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, `>screen`, выбрать "Capture full size screenshot" и нажать <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: криншот]

Получится скриншот всей страницы, который окажется в папке загрузок:

> [image: пример]

Answer (score 1):

нажмите f12 и поменяйте значение media=screen на медиа принт

Comment: Поменять во всех css-правилах вручную? А более автоматизированный способ?